# invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(int)’ to ‘int’ error?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and one of the programs was for a random number generator.
Once I wrote the program I got the following errors:

```
dice.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
dice.cpp:18: error: pointer to a function used in arithmetic
dice.cpp:18: error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(int)’ to ‘int’
```

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;
int randn(int n);
int main()
{
  int q;
  int n;
  int r;
  srand(time(NULL));
  cout<<"Enter a number of dice to roll: ";
  cin>>n;
  cout<<endl;

  for (q=1; q<=n; q++)
  {
    r=randn+1;  // <-- error here
    cout<<r<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

int randn(int n)
{
  return rand()%n;
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Maybe you are new to C++, but this `dice.cpp:18: error: pointer to a function used in arithmetic` is hard to misinterpret. Did you even try reading the error and looking at line 18 of your code?

Comment: @Praetorian, it's very easy to misinterpret if you're so new to C++ that you don't know what a pointer is. Then the message is just gibberish. (On the other hand, if you ignore the text and just pretend it says "There is an error at or shortly before this line, so go review your lecture notes," then it still works as a pretty good indicator.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that your problem is this line:

```
r=randn+1;
```

I believe that you meant to write

```
r = randn(/* some argument */) + 1; // Note parentheses after randn
```

The issue is that you're trying to call the function but forgetting to put in the parentheses indicating that you're making the call.  Since you're trying to roll a six-sided die, this should probably read

```
r = randn(6) + 1;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `error: pointer to a function used in arithmetic`
randn is a name that points to a function in your program, so that you can call the function.  You added a number to the name of a function.
`error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(int)’ to ‘int’`
When you see parenthesis touching in a _type_ `(*)(int)` that means it's a function name.  It cannot convert a function name to an integer, to do math with.

Answer (score 3):

You have this statement:

```
r=randn+1;
```

You probably meant to *call* the `randn` function, and that requires that you use parentheses and pass an actual argument:

```
r=randn(6)+1; // assuming six-sided dice
```

Without parentheses, the symbol `randn` refers to the *address* of the function, and C++ doesn't allow arithmetic operations on function pointers. The type of the function is `int (*)(int)` — pointer to a function accepting an int and returning an int.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the answer.

```
int main()
{
   int q;
   int n;
   int r;
   srand(time(NULL));
   cout<<"Enter a number of dice to roll: ";
   cin>>n;
   cout<<endl;

   for (q=1; q<=n; q++)
   {
      r=randn(6)+1;  // <-- u forget to pass the parameters
      cout<<r<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}

int randn(int n)
{
   return rand()%n;
}
```